# how to upload image using byte array

Tags: android, arrays, android-asynctask, http-post, android-image

I'm trying to upload image using this code:

```
   private String uploadFile() {
 String responseString = null;

 try {

  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL_M);



  Log.i("UploadApp", "upload url: " + Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL_M);


  AndroidMultiPartEntity entity;
  entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
   new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

    @Override
    public void transferred(long num) {
     // publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
    }
   });

  File sourceFile;
  sourceFile = new File(compressImage(filePath));

  Log.i("UploadApp", "file path: " + filePath);

  // Adding file data to http body

  entity.addPart("f", new FileBody(sourceFile)); //problem is here


  entity.addPart("category", new StringBody("Bill"));
  entity.addPart("description", new StringBody("test single"));
  entity.addPart("file", new StringBody("unknown1"));
  entity.addPart("clientid", new StringBody("4"));



  totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
  httppost.setEntity(entity);

  // Making server call
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

  int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
  if (statusCode == 200) {
   // Server response
   responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
  } else {
   responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: " + statusCode;
  }

 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  responseString = e.toString();
  Log.e("UploadApp", "exception: " + responseString);
 } catch (IOException e) {
  responseString = e.toString();
  Log.e("UploadApp", "exception: " + responseString);
 }

 return responseString;

}
```

I have a web service  for uploading image which has 5 parameters and 4 of them are string but one is byte array (byte[] f)

**main problem:** how to convert my source file(image) in byte array to upload the image on server in above code corresponding this web service.

Comment: Your code is already uploading the file as byte array. Normal multi part uploading does so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android  third party "AndroidAsync".You can do any things from this code.plz check this

> https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first of all ,from source file you can get absolute path then called upload method

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath = sourceFile.getAbsolutePath();


private String upload() {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);

    }
```

Comment: How to call ur method here:  entity.addPart("f", new FileBody(sourceFile));?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload any file using this code only send file name with dot extension file encode string

At server side send encode string and Base64.decode file string

> ```
> String strAttachmentCoded = "";
> private int PICK_PDF_REQUEST = 1;
> Uri filePath;
>
> @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>
>     if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
>         filePath = data.getData();
>         File uploadFile = new File(filePath.toString());
>         URI uri = URI.create(uploadFile.getPath());
>         try {
>             if (uploadFile != null) {
>                 File uploadFile1 = new File(uri);
>                 FileInputStream objFileIS = new FileInputStream(uploadFile1);
>                 ByteArrayOutputStream objByteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>                 byte[] byteBufferString = new byte[1024];
>                 int readNum;
>                 readNum = objFileIS.read(byteBufferString);
>                 while (readNum != -1) {
>                     Log.v("  ", "" + readNum);
>                     objByteArrayOS.write(byteBufferString, 0, readNum);
>                     //                system.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
>                     readNum = objFileIS.read(byteBufferString);
>                 }
>                 byte[] byteBinaryData = Base64.encode(objByteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
>                 strAttachmentCoded = String.valueOf(byteBinaryData);
>             }
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```